# Regular Expressions - Snowflake

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

enter image description hereI am trying to get text till the fourth "\n \n" from the below text. Can you please help me to write the snowflake expression for this issue.

> Hello Jeffrey,\n \nWe have not heard from you yet. I hope all is well with you.\n \nChecking in to gather your **Goosehead approved office location address**, so we can add you to our database here at ERGOS.  Once added here, we can schedule your laptop setup.\n \n*Goosehead **requires all agents** to be onboarded by ERGOS so that we can provide IT support as well as get your laptop in our database.*   \n \nDo you have a laptop ready for setup?

Comment: First, don't SHOUT! Next, you should try yourself before asking.

Answer (score 1):

so every thing up to the first `\n \n` can be fetched with [regexp_substr](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html) via:

```
select
    regexp_substr(column1, '.*\n \n') as match
from values 
('Hello Jeffrey,\n \nWe have not heard from you yet. I hope all is well with you.\n \nChecking in to gather your Goosehead approved office location address, so we can add you to our database here at ERGOS. Once added here, we can schedule your laptop setup.\n \nGoosehead requires all agents to be onboarded by ERGOS so that we can provide IT support as well as get your laptop in our database. \n \nDo you have a laptop ready for setup?');
```

| MATCH |
| --- |
| Hello Jeffrey, |

now, if we add a group around that `(` `)` and ask for 4 matches `{4}`, and swap to a smaller sample text, to make things less ugly for the output

```
select
    regexp_substr(column1, '(.*\n \n){4}') as match
from values 
('1111\n \n222222222222222\n \n3333333333333333\n \n44444444444444444\n \n55555555555555555555555');
```

gives:

| MATCH |
| --- |
| 1111 222222222222222 3333333333333333 44444444444444444 |

if you are expecting the `\n` in the output:

then

```
select
    column1,
    regexp_substr(column1, '[^\\\\]+\\\\n \\\\n') as match
from values 
('1111\\n \\n22222\\n \\n33333333\\n \\n4444444\\n \\n55555\\n \\66666\\n \\n7777');
```

shows how they need to be encoded in the SQL to output, and thus how to encode the match.

these matches greedy and gives:

| COLUMN1 | MATCH |
| --- | --- |
| 1111\n \n22222\n \n33333333\n \n4444444\n \n55555\n \66666\n \n7777 | 1111\n \n |

thus putting the grouping back in:

```
select
    column1,
    regexp_substr(column1, '([^\\\\]+\\\\n \\\\n){4}') as match
from values 
('1111\\n \\n22222\\n \\n33333333\\n \\n4444444\\n \\n55555\\n \\66666\\n \\n7777');
```

| COLUMN1 | MATCH |
| --- | --- |
| 1111\n \n22222\n \n33333333\n \n4444444\n \n55555\n \66666\n \n7777 | 1111\n \n22222\n \n33333333\n \n4444444\n \n |

Picture to example for escaped new lines:

[image: Escaped Data in input and output]

[image: New lines in Data as new lines, with escaped anti match pattern]

[image: simple times, when things just worked, like people said]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! Unfortunately, your code is not working for the string example I provided. I have tried to customize your code to make it work but I could not achieve it. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: it works with the string you provided, are you intending the `\n` to be turns into actual newline tokens?

Comment: For some reason it is not working with this string on my end. No, I am not intending the \n to be turns into actual newline tokens. I would appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Mr. Pilgrim, could you please show it with the example I provided, please? Once again, I sincerely appreciate your help and time!

Comment: The problem is I do not know what is in your DB. I also do not know you sre running this code, and both are very sensitive to encoding/escaping issues. Which is the heart of the problem. There is zero point me showing anymore becasue the first block of SQL with the update regex “works for me” which will not help you.

Comment: I see...
Thank you so much for your labor, help and time! I appreciate that! Kind Regards!

Comment: Mr. Pilgrim, Sorry bothering again. Unfortunately,

Comment: The string in my snowflake table includes "\n \n" as shown in my original example but in your example, they are missing in your column1. I am also providing the string below:

Hello Jeffrey,\n \nWe have not heard from you yet. I hope all is well with you.\n \nChecking in to gather your Goosehead approved office location address, so we can add you to our database here at ERGOS. Once added here, we can schedule your laptop setup.\n \nGoosehead requires all agents to be onboarded by ERGOS so that we can provide IT support as well as get your laptop in our database. \n \nDo you have a laptop?

Comment: you still don't understand escaping. I have given you everything you need, to learn.

Comment: And only now I understood what you mean. Can you please suggest how can I control escaping newlines (\n) please? Certainly, I googled but could not find how to turn the sensitivity for (\n) off. It is my last question. I promise.

Comment: still we are talking past each other. You ether have new lines `\n` as `\` `n`  or is a single "newline" character. After you know what you have in your data, you need to match it with you regex. `\n` will match a newline (because it is a new line) `\\n` will match a slash then n, BUT the parses of the SQL input, and REGEX parse both need to handle that escaping, thus on the SQL prompt you will need `\\\\n` to match. AND if this is in a stored proc, it will need be escaped again.

Comment: lastly, if you want to handle both real newline and escaped newlines, you will have to use a group block `((\\\\n)|\n)` to say, escaped OR not escaped.